# AutoMapper: Keep Destination Values of properties in nested collection when they don't exist in source collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to update the domain model with data from a DTO. I want to update it with Entity Framework so first i get the entity from db. Then comes the difficult part. I want to map the TransFreightResponseDto object onto Freight object, but at the same time to preserve IDs (guids) in the Freight object, not to break any relations. The problem is that while .Ignore() works for some nested objects which have one-to-one relation, I cannot find a way to preserve IDs of nested collection like Loads or Spots. So  here is the DTO:

```
    public class TransFreightResponseDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")] public int Id { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("shipment_external_id")] public string ShipmentExternalId { get; set; 
    
        [JsonProperty("spots")] public IEnumerable<SpotDto> Spots { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("loads")] public IEnumerable<LoadDto> Loads { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("requirements")] public RequirementsDto Requirements { get; set; }
    
        [JsonProperty("payment")] public PaymentDto Payment { get; set; }
    }

    public class LoadDto
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")] public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("load_id")] public string LoadId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type_of_load")] public string TypeOfLoad { get; set; }
    }
```

And here are the destination models:

```
public class Freight : BaseEntity
{
    public int TransId { get; set; }

    public string ShipmentExternalId { get; set; }

    public string ExternalSource { get; set; }

    public bool Publish { get; set; }

    public Payment Payment { get; set; }

    public Requirements Requirements { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Spot> Spots { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Load> Loads { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Carrier> Carriers { get; set; }

}

    public class Load : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string LoadId { get; set; }

        public string TypeOfLoad { get; set; }

        public Guid FreightId { get; set; }

        public virtual Freight Freight { get; set; }
    }

    public class BaseEntity : IBaseEntity
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
    }
```

And this is how I map:

```
    foreach (Freight freight in freightsToUpdate)
    {
        TransFreightResponseDto freightResponse = responseList.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ShipmentExternalId == freight.ShipmentExternalId);
        Freight mappedFreight = this._mapper.Map(freightResponse, freight);
        mappedFreightsList.Add(mappedFreight);
    }
```

Mapping I defined is this:

```
        this.CreateMap<TransFreightResponseDto, Freight>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.TransId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Payment, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

So the exact problem is that while most of the model maps correctly, for example Payment in the DTO is null and it is correctly ignored, all the IDs of dependent entities, which are represented by collections (Loads, Spots) have their Guids set to the default value. I tried using .Ignore() just like I used it for the parent entity, I tried using UseDestinationValue() but nothing works. Below I put the example mapping I created, I tried using Ignore() and UseDestinationValue separately and together as I ran out of ideas:

```
        this.CreateMap<SpotDto, Spot>().PreserveReferences()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FreightId, opt => opt.UseDestinationValue())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Id, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.FreightId, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Research AutoMapper.Collection.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. You sounds like you want the id of the dtos in the models but that you then tried to use Ignore(). Why would you ignore the dto id if that's what you want?

Comment: @sr28 I used Ignore() on the IDs of the destination entities. It's not about ignoring the id of the DTO, that's a completely different thing. I tried to Ignore() the Ids of the destination entities to prevent mapping anything onto them (the source DTO doesn't have such properties though). I edited my question slightly, maybe now it is clearer.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I researched it a bit but don't know what you mea exactly. Besides VS is complaining that the newest version of AutoMapper is outside of dependency constraint and I would have to downgrade it significantly.

Comment: AutoMapper clears collections in the destination object, regardless of whether or not they are mapped. If you want to update one from a source collection, AutoMapper.Collection is available. Otherwise, there is no way around it.